# usage of had been in absence

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

His father had to pawn the earrings.

> The earrings were gone for a long time.

If I change this sentence in such a way that it means exactly as 
"The earrings had been in absence."
I wanted to know the usage "had been in absence" is
right or wrong.

Comment: The usage is correct, but why do you want to use the _past perfect_ here? It only makes sense if you are trying to say something like: "By the time she replaced them, the earrings had been in absence for a long time." The _past perfect_ describes the past from a perspective in the past.

Comment: Also, just to be clear: "in absence" is not synonymous with "gone." You could not say: "That train is in absence."

Comment: I doubt anyone would say "The earrings had been in absence."  Even in simple past "The earrings were absent." implies the earrings went somewhere on there own accord. You should add an explanation to your question regarding why you want to say "The earrings had been in absence."

Comment: His father had to pawn the earrings.

Comment: Why not just post the actual question from the exercise? (e.g. this one from  [**2104.**](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/215562-absence-disappearance))

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for providing the link.I really wish to know your opinion about this question .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the first two comments. Oh, and the link was from 2014.

Comment: Is ''had been in absence'' wrong? O.K what is the right answer?

Comment: Please read and understand the comments. The usage _had been in absence_ is grammatically correct, but a native English speaker would never express this thought as you have done unless the circumstances were extraordinarily complicated. The comments are written in very simple English. What about them do you not understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44943/discussion-between-learner-and-p-e-dant).

Comment: According to the context in the OP, I think it means "the earrings were in pawn".